# APIM - cache request with authorization header for all users (not per user)

Tags: caching, azure-api-management, azure-redis-cache, azure-caching

I have a backend API service that requires bearer-token authorization, and it is fronted by Azure API Management.  One particular endpoint returns a large dataset (at least 3MB in size) but the endpoint has no parameters so any given response is valid for all users.

I have an external Azure Redis Cache configured for this APIM instance, and I want to add caching to this one endpoint, with the response cached for ALL users (not per-user).

**To start off, I'm trying to get this working on a different parameter-less endpoint that only returns a 3Kb response - when I get it working, I'll apply the policy to the 3MB+ endpoint.**

I tried adding a simple **cache-store/cache-lookup** policy:

```
<cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false"
              downstream-caching-type="none" caching-type="external" />
```

But that didn't work, and the following *cache-lookup* trace message was displayed:

```
"Request contains Authorization header. Cache Lookup policy was not applied."
```

So, I had to add another parameter to the *cache-lookup* policy:

```
allow-private-response-caching="true"
```

When I did this, the *cache-lookup* ran, but the trace message showed it was a miss:

```
{
    "message": "Cache lookup resulted in a miss. Cache headers listed below were removed from the request to prompt the backend service to send back a complete response.",
    "cacheKey": "**************************************************************",
    "cacheHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the cache-store trace message said that the response would be cached:

```
"Response will be buffered during streaming and stored in the cache after it is received in full."
```

So I ran the trace again, but it resulted in another "cache miss".  No matter how many times I run the trace, it always says the cache is a miss, but the cache-key is identical every time.  The cache duration is 3600, so the response *should* be cached for an hour.

**If the key isn't changing, why does each lookup always result in a miss?**

Answer (score 1):

Check if my below findings help to fix your issue:

- If your request comes within the cache duration specified such as 3600 seconds, then the result will be `Cache lookup resulted in a hit` instead of `Cache lookup resulted in a miss` under Inbound Section.
- Also, Check in the policy-chain that cache-lookup policy should be written before the Cache-store section, also correctly scoped to the target gateway such as Product of APIs, Operations or the API level and then try re-run by clearing the cache.
- And If your APIM is in Consumption tier, this would be one of the reasons for getting the message like `Cache lookup resulted in a miss.` In Consumption Tier of Azure APIM, you have to use external Redis compatible cache as specified in this GitHub Issue #[43964](https://github.com/microsoftdocs/azure-docs/issues/43964).

> **If the key isn't changing, why does each lookup always result in a miss?**

This could be because of the cache policy which is set in APIM.

- If the policy is set to cache the response based on the request parameters, then each request with different request parameters will result in a cache miss.
- If the policy is configured to cache the response for a short period, each consecutive request results in a cache miss.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a configuration on the NSG (Network Security Group) that was preventing communication between APIM and the REDIS server on the ports that Redis requires.

**FIX - We had to create Inbound/Outbound security rules to allow communication on ports 6380-6383 and this resolved the issue.**

Thanks for your input!